# MATLAB:"matrix index is out of range for deletion"

Tags: matlab

I have a data structure that has a cell array "mydata", which has 250 rows of cells that look like this:

```
{1x1 cell}
{1x2 cell}
{1x4 cell}
{1x1 cell}
.
.
.
```

I want to have separate files which are only 1x1, but at the same time. I don't wanna change the length of my cell array and instead want to find a way to pass any extra component to new files and if there is nothing extra, it becomes an empty cell.For example, if one cell is 1x2 with cells like "rose" and "blue", in one file I wanna have "rose" and in the other file, "blue" to be saved.

I get "matrix index is out of range for deletion" for the following script. What is the issue in it? Is there any more straightfoward way to do what I want?
Part of what I've done:

```
mydata= structure.mydata; 

first_file = cell(numel(mydata),1);

second_file = cell(numel(mydata),1);


for i = 1 : length(structure.mydata)

    content = structure.mydata(i);

    first_file(i) = content(1);

    if length(content) > 1

    second_file(i) = content(2);

    else

    second_file(i) = [];

    end

end
```

Comment: I recommend that you run your program step by step in the debugger and see what type and size `content` is. Are you aware of the difference between indexing with () and {}?

Comment: No, not really, but well, any of them gave me the same error.

Comment: Then you should start learning how cell indexing works. Read here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html